# how do i open up and run an asp.net project compiled in windows on a mac OS X?

Tags: asp.net, macos

i need to make some changes to an asp.net website developed by another person - he is on a windows machine, i am using a mac.

i need to make some fairly minor changes to the asp, but obviously i can't without being able to at least run the project, and hopefully open it in some development environment (although i'm not adverse to doing it all with a text editor if that's 'easier').

i have installed monodevelop, but can't see how to open the project, let alone run it!

maybe it's easier to do this in parallels in a windows environment?

please help!

:)

Comment: If you have paralells then I'd use that, particularly if this project is to be deployed in a windows environment.

Answer (score 0):

If the changes are to the front end page, look for the actual `.aspx` page - this is a text file and you should be able to simply change it and have the changes be reflected.

If this is deeper down (i.e. in the code behind or other source code), you should be able to open the web project (look for a `.cproj` or `.vbproj` file or better, a `.sln` for the whole solution) - this should open fine in monodevelop.

If it was setup as a website, rather than a web project, there will be no project file and you should be able to create a web project in monodevelop and simply add all of the files/folders to it in order to work on it.